# Recently viewed/report issue Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, reports, ce-1.9.2.1

We've got a few issues which I believe are all related to the same thing, I've looked into this various times and haven't got close to a solution:

1. Recently viewed doesn't work i.e. does not display any products for logged in and logged out users (product pages)
2. On the dashboard, 'Most Viewed Products' is empty
3. Table 'report_viewed_product_index' is empty/does not update - 'log_*' tables do not update either

It is my understanding that recently viewed is part of Mage Reports hence why I think these are all related. Ultimately, we want the recently viewed to work. The rest is a bonus.

I've tried:

- Clearing the logs on command line
- Refresh statistics
- Various variations of showing recently viewed (see below)
- Creating a CMS widget for recently viewed
- Checked catalog.xml for appropriate recent product script

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed'); ?>`

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed'); ?>`

`<?php $collection = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')->getItemsCollection(); ?>`

Our development website did have all of the above working (for reasons I won't go into, that development website is no longer accessible - we've seen had to create a new development website from the live website). The website build/files were the same.

We're working on Magento 1.9.2.1

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you refresh lifetime statistics? There's a dropdown in the backend grid you have to toggle.

Comment: I did indeed refresh lifetime statistics.

Comment: Have you tried disabling community/local modules to see whether there is any conflicting code? Did you check for core hacks which might modify system behavior?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. We never actually got to the bottom of this and it's become a priority to resolve. We've disabled all modules and still the issue continues and there are no core hacks. The relevant report tables are never updated and are always blank. I assume that the recently viewed widget will not show if there are no stats available. We've checked the CRON and timezone (Magento, local.xml and PHP are all consistent) as this could have been the cause. I'm running out of ideas - grateful for any further suggestions.

Comment: Further to my last comment, I’ve updated Mangeto to version 1.9.2.4 and other extensions which needed upgrading.

Comment: Scratch this, after hours and hours of searching... I found an extension which wasn't disabling correctly and disabled catalog_controller_product_view... hopefully this helps someone.